# Installing Gem therubyracer on windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, therubyracer

Guys today I was trying to install old project "developed by **rails3**" on my Pc so after type the commands

```
bundle install 

rails s
```

It gave me the error

```
Please install gem 'therubyracer' to use Less.
```

then I installed the **Gem therubyracer** by doing this steps

first activated my code encoding

```
C:\>chcp 1252
Active code page: 1252
```

then downloaded the Gem files for windows from this page 
https://github.com/hiranpeiris/therubyracer_for_windows

and typed the commands

```
C:\>cd therubyracer_for_windows-master

C:\therubyracer_for_windows-master>gem install "therubyracer-0.11.0beta1-x86-min
gw32.gem"
Successfully installed therubyracer-0.11.0beta1-x86-mingw32
Parsing documentation for therubyracer-0.11.0beta1-x86-mingw32
Done installing documentation for therubyracer after 3 seconds
1 gem installed

C:\therubyracer_for_windows-master>cd..

C:\>cd sites

C:\Sites>cd siteFolder

C:\Sites>cd siteFolder> bundle install

C:\Sites\siteFolder>rails s
```

then I found my self got the same error !!! 
why ?
the gem now installed , why I got the same error ???

```
[WARNING] Please install gem 'therubyracer' to use Less.
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/less-2.5.0/lib/less/java_sc
ript/v8_context.rb:2:in `require': cannot load such file -- v8 (LoadError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/less-2.5.0/lib
/less/java_script/v8_context.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/less-2.5.0/lib
/less/java_script.rb:9:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/less-2.5.0/lib
/less/java_script.rb:9:in `default_context_wrapper'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/less-2.5.0/lib
/less/java_script.rb:17:in `context_wrapper'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/less-2.5.0/lib
/less/loader.rb:13:in `initialize'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/less-2.5.0/lib
/less.rb:14:in `new'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/less-2.5.0/lib
/less.rb:14:in `<module:Less>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/less-2.5.0/lib
/less.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/less-rails-2.5
.0/lib/less/rails.rb:6:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/less-rails-2.5
.0/lib/less/rails.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/less-rails-2.5
.0/lib/less-rails.rb:1:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/less-rails-2.5
.0/lib/less-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.6.2/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.6.2/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.6.2/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.6.2/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.6.2/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.6.2/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.6.2/
lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
        from C:/Sites/siteFolder/config/application.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'

C:\Sites\siteFolder>
```

Comment: You've downloaded a 32 bit gem, are you sure your ruby isn't running a 64 bit version?

Have you tried running gem install therubyracer?

Comment: Yes I'm on 32 bit  and it installed well but when open the project I found it notify me to install the gem !!!, when i try to install it like [gem install therubyracer] it gave me the error 
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - C:/Users/Astm/.gem/specs/api.rubygems.org%443/latest_specs.4.8

Comment: The errors are probably because you don't have the rubydev kit installed. This is required to download gems, download 'DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20111229-1559-sfx.exe' from http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/.

Permission denied, are you running CMD as admin? right click->run as administrator

Comment: I'm already has DevKit

Comment: Have you tried running command-line as administrator before running gem install?

Comment: Just install nodejs and restart your pc so that rails can pick it up. Also remove 'therubyracer' from your gemfile

Comment: After run the CMD as admin I also got the same error  :(

Comment: After install Nodejs and restart my PC and run the CMD as admin and typed the commant [C:\Sites\siteFolder>gem install therubyracer]
I got the ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - C:/Users/Astm/.gem/specs/api.rubygems.org%443/late
st_specs.4.8